# Replace a substring contained between two substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

`'bookmarkState={"params":{"date_from":"2014-07-31","date_to":"2014-10-01"}}'`

I want to replace `2014-07-31` with `2014-01-01`, i.e. the substring contained between '"date_from":"' and '","', using a regular expression in javascript. I have written this code but it doesn't work:

```
var qs = 'bookmarkState={"params":{"date_from":"2014-07-31","date_to":"2014-10-01"}};'
var regEx = /^(.*?date_from":")[^"]*(".*)$/;
qs = qs.replace(regEx, '2014-01-01');`
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regex to do that:

```
eval('bookmarkState={"params":{"date_from":"2014-07-31","date_to":"2014-10-01"}}');

bookmarkState.params.date_from = '1988-04-12';

console.log(JSON.stringify(bookmarkState));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?date_from":")[^"]*(",".*)$
```

Try this.Replace by `$1<your string>$2`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ0uP0/1

Comment: I write this code but it doesn't work
var qs = bookmarkState={"params":{"date_from":"2014-07-31","date_to":"2014-10-01"}}';
var regExp = /^(.*?date_from":")[^"]*(".*)$/;
qs = qs.replace(regExp, '2014-01-01');

Comment: @RobertoGentili you need to use replace()

Comment: @RobertoGentili you need to use flag `re.Multiline`

Comment: var qs = 'bookmarkState={"params":{"date_from":"2014-07-31","date_to":"2014-10-01"}}';
var regEx = new RegExp('^(.*?date_from":")[^"]*(".*)$', 'm');
qs = qs.replace(regExp, '2014-01-01');

Doesn't works (flag m setted)

Comment: @RobertoGentili replace text will be `$1<something>$2` and what is the error